# Why is karate-gatling slow compared to JMeter

Tags: karate

I have followed the example at [karate-gatling-demo](https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo) for creating a load test.  For my use-case I converted a JMeter test to karate.  After making sure everything works, I compared the two.  In the time that it took karate-gatling to get to even 300 requests, JMeter had already made a few thousands.  I thought it might have been the pause in the demo but even after I removed it, the speed of the tests make them unusable.  I would really like to implement this as we are already making strides to use normal karate tests as part of our CI process.  Is there a reason they are so slow?

(I am using karate-gatling version `0.8.0.RC4`)

To provide some info related to the two testing situations...

- JMeter: 50 threads/users with 30 second ramp up and 50 loops
- Karate-Gatling: repeat scenario 50 times, ramp to 50 users over 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is still in the early stages of development. This feedback helps. If possible can you try 0.8.0.RC3 and see if that makes a difference, the test syntax needs a slight change which you should be able to figure out from the version history. There was a fundamental change in the async model which probably has some issues.

Ideally I would love someone who knows Gatling internals to help but this will take a little time to evolve with me looking at it.

EDIT: Gatling support was released in 0.8.0 (final) and multiple teams have reported that it is working well for them.

Comment: Going back to to RC3 definitely made a difference in speed.  RC4 stayed around 100-200 request/minute but it looks like RC3 is somewhere around 300-500.

Comment: @Matthew ok thanks that helps. you'll need to be patient while we figure this out ! but I'm confident we can solve this soon. if you can contribute a JMeter comparison test, that would be great.

Comment: Alright.  Very happy with my experience with Karate so far and trying to convince my team/business to adopt it too.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: an update - there is some good progress on this - being tracked here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/438